# match and location prop not updating after link to

Tags: reactjs

I am having a weird issue where I have a link to on a page and it is changing the url but not reloading the page.

In this case it is the same component with a different ID.  It seems like match.params is not being updated even though the url changes.

I checked the props directly on render and they do get updated but show the same value I had.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt finish the question and was not going to post but after the crazy amount of research and not much out there here is what I found.

Using React Router loading the same component you need to add withRouter inorder for the match and location to update with the new url.

My router link was like `/somepart/:id`
And I was linking to that same url with a different ID.  No problem when going from a different component.

### Solution

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

...

class MyComponent extends Component {
    render() {
    const { myID } = this.props.match.params
    return (
        ...
    )
}

...

export default withRouter(MyComponent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider a basic `Page` component, using `match.params` to link to the next page:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default ({match}) => {
  const id = parseInt(match.params.id);
    return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <p>This is page {id}</p>
      <Link to={`/page/${id + 1}`}>Next</Link>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
};
```

It should work just fine if mounted from a `Route`:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Page from './Page';

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Link to="/page/1">First Page</Link>} />
      <Route component={Page} exact path="/page/:id" />
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

See https://codesandbox.io/s/lw9j5zq4m for a live example.

Comment: I started from a template.  It uses async loading of the components.  Maybe that is the problem with my router.